# Bitmap - wrong coordinates

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, bitmap

When I take the mouse coordinates relative to the top left corner and set that pixel to a colour, that pixel is not at the mouse's position and it even differs from bitmap to bitmap. At one bitmap the coordinates seemed to be multiplied by 0.8 but the second one I tried was like *0.2. I tried using PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;, that also didn't work. I think the bitmaps might be set to use different pixel size but even if that's the case, I don't know how to handle that.

Comment: Let me guess: You have the images in a PictureBox and the sizeMode  is not Normal?

Comment: I take a Graphics object from PaintEventArgs in the Paint event and then use DrawImage.

Comment: And where do the mouse coordinates from? You should post the relevant code!

Comment: MouseEventArgs in MouseMove event, I didn't want to have to post the code because there is a lot of code that is not relevant to the question and I also use many extension methods.

Comment: When I just draw something using the Graphics object directly, not through the bitmap, it worked perfectly.

Comment: You will have to show us at least a little. At the moment we don't even know what control you are drawing on. Please strip out the stuff that doesn't belong to the problem or better yet, create a minimal solution that shows the problem.. What does the DrawImage call look like? does it have source or target offset or scaling?

Comment: I'm actually so dumb that I didn't realize recreating the problem in a new app is a way, it'll be here shortly.

Comment: It is not dumb it is tunnel-vision. Do check the DrawImage call though fist! It can scale the bitmap or have offsets on target and/or source..!

Comment: g.DrawImage(Bmp, 0, 0); just like this, no scaling, as I said, two different bitmaps behaved differently using the exact same code

Comment: Oh yes, pixel sizes may differ, sort of. It is called dpi resolution and you should make sure they are are the same as the screen/graphics object  has! You can set them in the Bitmaps before using them..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your bitmaps have varying dpi settings.

You may need to correct them to be the same as the Graphics object has:

```
Bmp.SetResolution(g.DpiX, g.DpiY);
g.DrawImage(Bmp, 0, 0);
```